# How to store all file names from the directory and save it in excel?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, directory, export-to-excel

Good evening Everyone.

i wrote a small piece of code (Got help from this stackoverflow Search)

I could able to get the list of files from the directory.

I tried to store in Excel Spreadsheet. I could able to store only two lines of the file in excel, but not all the file names.

Please check the code and output.

Help me a solution to list all file names in the excel.

Thanks a million.

code:-

```
import os
import pandas as pd
path = "//home//halovivek//Downloads//education//Jimi Kwik - Super Brain//"
list = []
for (root,dirs, file) in os.walk(path):
    for f in file:
        print(f)

my_data = pd.DataFrame(file)
my_data.to_excel("outputfile.xlsx", index = False, header= False)
```

> output:-
>
> /home/halovivek/PycharmProjects/yearcoding/venv/bin/python
> /home/halovivek/PycharmProjects/yearcoding/26082002_listfilesfromdirectory.py
> Day 12 - Implementation Day - Juggling Exercise.mp4 Day 12 -
> Implementation Day - Juggling Exercise.MP3 Part 2 - Preparing For The
> Quest.mp4 Part 1 - Welcome To Your 30-Day Superbrain Quest.mp4 Part 5
>
> - 10 Morning Habits Geniuses Use To Jump Start The Brain.mp4 Part 3 - The FAST Method For Learning Anything.mp4 Part 2 - Preparing For The
>   Quest.MP3 Part 1 - Welcome To Your 30-Day Superbrain Quest.MP3 Part 5
> - 10 Morning Habits Geniuses Use To Jump Start The Brain.MP3 Part 4 - How To Take Notes.mp4 Part 3 - The FAST Method For Learning
>   Anything.MP3 Part 4 - How To Take Notes.MP3 Day 27 - The Ancient
>   Alphanumeric Code Of Memory Part 2 - Application.MP3 Day 27 - The
>   Ancient Alphanumeric Code Of Memory Part 2 - Application.mp4 Day 29 -
>   The 5 Levels Of Transformation.MP3 Day 29 - The 5 Levels Of
>   Transformation.mp4 Day 14 - Memory Is As Easy As PIE.MP3 Day 14 -
>   Memory Is As Easy As PIE.mp4 Day 15 - The FDR Technique.MP3 Day 15 -
>   The FDR Technique.mp4 Day 31 - Overcoming Procrastination.mp4 Day 31 -
>   Overcoming Procrastination.MP3 Day 9 - Chain Linking - Part 1.mp4 Day
>   9 - Chain Linking - Part 1.MP3 Day 8 - Implementation Day - Morning
>   Routine.mp4 Day 8 - Implementation Day - Morning Routine.MP3 Day 24 -
>   Implementation Day - Crossovers.MP3 Day 24 - Implementation Day -
>   Crossovers.mp4 Day 19 - Learning Foreign Languages.mp4 Day 19 -
>   Learning Foreign Languages.MP3 Day 13 - BE SUAVE Remembering Names.MP3
>   Day 13 - BE SUAVE Remembering Names.mp4 Day 34 - Speed Reading.MP3 Day
>   34 - Speed Reading.mp4 Day 22 - The Location Method.MP3 Day 22 - The
>   Location Method.mp4 Day 5 - Nutrition _ Your Body Folders.MP3 Day 5 -
>   Nutrition _ Your Body Folders.mp4 Day 23 - Memorize Word For Word.MP3
>   Day 23 - Memorize Word For Word.mp4 Day 30 - Q&A Session with Jim.mp4
>   Day 30 - The 5 Levels Of Learning.mp4 Day 30 - The 5 Levels Of
>   Learning.MP3 Day 30 - Q&A with Jim.MP3 Day 28 - Implementation Day -
>   Phonetic Number Code.MP3 Day 28 - Implementation Day - Phonetic Number
>   Code.mp4 How To Become A Super Learner Masterclass - Jim Kwik.mp4
>   how_to_become_a_super_learner_by_jim_kwik_workbook_nsp.pdf Day 18 -
>   Keyword Substitution Method.MP3 Day 18 - Keyword Substitution
>   Method.mp4 Day 32 - Your 8 C's To Muscle Memory.mp4 Day 32 - Your 8
>   C's To Muscle Memory.MP3 Day 4 - Implementation Day - Spaced
>   Repetition Concept.mp4 Day 4 - Implementation Day - Spaced Repetition
>   Concept.MP3 Day 26 - The Ancient Alphanumeric Code Of Memory Part 1 -
>   The Sounds.MP3 Day 26 - The Ancient Alphanumeric Code Of Memory Part 1
> - The Sounds.mp4 Day 2 - The Sun Is Up.mp4 Day 2 - The Sun Is Up.MP3 Day 16 - Implementation Day - Superbrain Yoga.MP3 Day 16 -
>   Implementation Day - Superbrain Yoga.mp4 Day 10 - Chain Linking - Part
>   2.MP3 Day 10 - Chain Linking - Part 2.mp4 .getxfer.14810.259.mega Day 7 - Sleep _ Stress Management.MP3 Day 7 - Sleep _ Stress
>   Management.mp4 Day 33 - Remembering Your Dreams.mp4 Day 33 -
>   Remembering Your Dreams.MP3 .getxfer.14709.10.mega
>   .getxfer.28947.5.mega Day 21 - How To Give A Speech Without Notes.MP3
>   .getxfer.27388.5.mega Day 3 - The 10 Keys To Unlocking Your
>   Superbrain.mp4 .getxfer.10040.5.mega Day 6 - Environments _ Killing
>   ANTs.MP3
>   _Groupinsiders.com.url Day 6 - Environments _ Killing ANTs.mp4 Day 25 - Numbers - The Basics.mp4 Day 25 - Numbers - The Basics.MP3 Day 1 - M.O.M. Can Help You Remember.MP3 Day 1 - M.O.M. Can Help You
>   Remember.mp4 Day 20 - Implementation Day - Counting To 10 In
>   Japanese.MP3 Day 20 - Implementation Day - Counting To 10 In
>   Japanese.mp4 Day 11 - The Peg Memory Method.MP3 Day 11 - The Peg
>   Memory Method.mp4 Day 17 - The Ultimate TIP To Remembering
>   Anything.MP3 Day 17 - The Ultimate TIP To Remembering Anything.mp4
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

[image]

Comment: So do you want to update an existing spreadsheet with these files? Or just create a new one with a list of the files?

Comment: I want to create a new spreadsheet and store it

Comment: Adding more information to the Question. The output is not showing all files from inside the directory. it is skipping the files and printing in the output.

Answer (score 0):

You're issues here... 'list' is a keyword in python.. so can't be used as a variable name when you try to declare a list..
You're not actually doing anything with your values in your loop
Glob is slightly easier for working through directories

```
import glob
list_of_files = []
for file_or_dir in glob.glob("//home//halovivek//Downloads//education//Jimi Kwik - Super Brain//**", recursive = True):
        if os.path.isfile(file_or_dir) 
                list_of_mp3s_mp4s.append(file_or_dir)
my_data = pd.DataFrame(list_of_mp3s)
my_data.to_excel("outputfile.xlsx", index = False, header= False)
```

Comment: I haven't tested this never used .to_excel() method before, so don't know if it will work

Comment: hi i dont want to list only mp3 files. I want to list all the files.

Comment: Tried above code and got this error./home/halovivek/PycharmProjects/yearcoding/venv/bin/python /home/halovivek/PycharmProjects/yearcoding/27082022_listfilesfromdirectory.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/halovivek/PycharmProjects/yearcoding/27082022_listfilesfromdirectory.py", line 5, in <module>
    for file_or_dir in glob("//home//halovivek//Downloads//education//Jimi Kwik - Super Brain//**", recursive = True):
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: I've edited the code above.. your error message there is because the module was called as a method instead of the method inside the module. glob.glob("//home//halovivek//Downloads//education//Jimi Kwik - Super Brain//**", recursive = True) should call the method within the module

Comment: The above code is working . But there is no data in the excel file. it shows just empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import pandas as pd
#path of the file you want to enemurate
path = "//home//halovivek//Downloads//"
directory =[]
filename=[]

for (root,dirs, file) in os.walk(path):
    for f in file:
        directory.append(root)
        filename.append(f)
        print(f)

#column name of the sheet
df=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(directory,filename)),columns=['Directory',"filename"])
#change the file of exccl sheet
df.to_csv("all.csv")
```

It will list all files and store it in the spreadsheet in csv format.
I tested and its working fine.